# WPF: Grid inside Border inside Popup?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

So, my simplified XAML looks like:

```
<Popup>
    <Border>
        <Grid Name="TROUBLEMAKER">
            <ListBox ... />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

During runtime: 
Border's `ActualHeight` is, for example, 500.
Grid's (`Name="TROUBLEMAKER"`) `ActualHeight` might be **10 000**, and as consequence virtualization (`ListBox` inside the `TROUBLEMAKER`) does not work: it assumes there is enough space to render everything without any sophisticated recycling/other default WPF's techniques.

The funniest thing that even though I can specify `MaxHeight=...`, it won't obey and still gonna take as much space as needed to render all elements (concrete number varies from 20 items to 20 000).

Any ideas how to tackle this problem down?

Comment: @mm8 inside of the grid there are pretty standard `ListBox`es, they do use pretty standart virtualization. Indeed, I've checked: `VirtualizingStackPanel` is there and all the proeprties are correct.

Comment: There is no ListBox mentioned in your question. You may want to update and include a MCVE of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try to bind grid's `height` to borders `ActualHeight`